# PhpStorm not detecting php library namespace

Tags: php, phpstorm, .so

I'm using PhpStorm as current IDE.

The only issue I have with it is that it can't find my php-library.

I've installed this: [PHP-JS](http://php-javascript.com/).

And by install, i mean generated the `php-js.so` file which I've loaded via `php5enmod php-js`.

The library works:

```
// This is a valid namespace AND classname
$context = new JS\Context;
$result  = $context->evaluate("var x = 3; var y = 4; var z = x + y; ++z;");
// will output 8
```

For some (well, not that strange) reason, PhpStorm can't find the `JS` namespace and consequently no classes from that namespace.

Is there a way I can tell PhpStorm that I'm actually calling an existing method from a valid class from a valid namespace?

I've tried to make it work using docBlock tags but none seems to match what I need.

Comment: There is NO WAY that PhpStorm will read your binary `.so` file and detect PHP code/interface from there. You need to do the same as ALL other binary php extensions do (e.g. [Phalcon](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html#integrating-tools-with-phpstorm-ide)) -- makes stubs (limited PHP version) of your classes (classes/methods/functions/etc with full doc but empty bodies). You can `Ctrl+Click` on any standard PHP class (e.g. MySQL) and see how it's done yourself.

Comment: @LazyOne, I'm not expecting PhpStorm to read my `.so` file. I'm asking *how* to let it know i'm actually using a valid namespace. And not mark it as invalid

Comment: @AlexTartan Like LazyOne said, PhpStorm only knows the namespaces when there are stubs for it or full plaintext classes referenced via composer/include. See GitHub repo of JetBrains PhpStorm method stubs: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs

Comment: @AlexTartan Just do as I have said in my last sentence (or follow the link DanFromGermany has provided) -- it's the same stuff. Once you see how it's done there .. you can do exactly the same with your stubs for that PHP-JS library. Then just place them anywhere in your project -- it will be used by IDE only.

Comment: @LazyOne, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm gonna make stubs for each class.

Comment: @LazyOne, Can you please make these comments an answer, so I can properly thank you for helping out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way that PhpStorm will read your binary `.so` file (`.dll` on Windows) and extract PHP interfaces from there (and by "PHP interface" I mean classes/functions/constants/etc that extension offers during runtime).

Therefore you would need to do the same as all other binary php extensions would do (e.g. [Phalcon's DevTools](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html#integrating-tools-with-phpstorm-ide)) -- make stubs files.

Stub file is a limited PHP version of your classes/methods/functions/etc with (optional) full doc but empty bodies. You can <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on any standard PHP class (e.g. `MySQL`) and see yourself how it's done in PhpStorm (IDE will open corresponding stub file in another editor tab) .. or just browse their stub repository directly (thanks @DanFromGermany for the link -- https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs).

An example of such stub file would be (it covers the code from your example):

```
<?php

namespace JS;

class Context
{
    /**
     * Evaluate your JS code
     *
     * @param string $param JS code to evaluate
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function evaluate($param) {}
}
```

Just place such stub files somewhere in your project (or reference any other supported way -- e.g. via `PHP | Include paths`) -- this code is for IDE only.

---

Such stub files can be used by any IDE/editor that can parse source `.php` files and offer classes/functions from there in code completion. Therefore it makes perfect sense to [ask developers](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-JS/issues) of that PHP-JS to provide such stubs automatically (just like Phalcon devs do).