# How to enable autocomplete in PhpStorm for Datatrax php-driver

Tags: database, cassandra, phpstorm

Is it possible to activate autocomplete in PhpStorm for Cassandra DataStax php-driver.

I tried the PHPAdvancedAutocomplete extension in PhpStorm but didn't helped.

The driver is loaded as extension. It is also known in phpinfo();.

[DataStax php-driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-php-driver/php-driver/whatsNew.html)

Comment: *"So it should be available in autocomplete."* Nope. No IDE is able to read your extension's compiled binary code and interpret it for code completion. Have a look at these similar Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30329412/783119 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/35923482/783119

Comment: Basically -- see if they have stub files for PHP (or maybe somebody else did them already). If they do -- reference them in your code in any supported way (e.g. place in separate folder anywhere in the project so that IDE can index it). If they don't -- you may [create such stub file yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35923482/783119). Otherwise you will have to live with those errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all future visitors of this question. Here is the answer.

Checkout that repository.

[PHP-Cassandra-Stub (for DataStax php-driver)](https://github.com/hauptmedia/php-cassandra-stub)