# PhpStorm cannot recognize the function in the opentelemetry extension

Tags: php, windows, phpstorm, open-telemetry

I downloaded the OpenTelemetry Windows DLL, and referenced it in the php.ini file.

`php -mi` shows the opentelemetry has been loaded.

```
php -mi | grep telemetry
opentelemetry
```

`php -r`  shows the function exists:

```
php -r "print_r(get_extension_funcs('opentelemetry'));"
Array
(
    [0] => OpenTelemetry\Instrumentation\hook
)
```

In PhpStorm's PHP Interpreter also configured the exact PHP, as when I execute `phpinfo` from PhpStorm's run button, it shows the opentelemetry in loaded. I can also get the tracing data when run the code in PhpStorm which imply the extension works.

But why PhpStorm does not recognize the function in the extension?

[image]

Comment: Did you expect PhpStorm to automatically detect that you have installed a new extension, and extract metadata from it?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: *"Yes, is it possible?"* No. You have to have "stub files" that describe those classes/functions/constants/etc to PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm uses **stub files** for providing code completion (and static analysis) for functionality provided by custom PHP extensions/modules (that come from `.dll` / `.so` files).

Stub file is a limited PHP version of those classes/methods/functions/etc with (optional) full PHPDoc block but empty bodies. Overall it's something similar to what `.h` files are in C. You can <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on any standard PHP class/function (e.g. `MySQL` or `str_replace()`) and see yourself how it's done (the IDE will open corresponding stub file in another editor tab). A bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35923482/783119

- PhpStorm keeps all known-to-them/made-by-them stubs in their main repository: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs. It is bundled with every PhpStorm version.
- It already contains the stub for OpenTelemetry: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/opentelemetry/opentelemetry.php
- I do not see the `opentelemetry` entry in the GUI yet in my current stable 2023.2.4 version (`Settings/Preferences | PHP | PHP Runtime`) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2023.2/php.html#php-runtime-tab. This suggests that it will be bundled in the next major 2023.3 version only (to be release soon: next week or two). Unless I cannot just locate it there...

---

**What you can do right now:**

1. Try the latest **2023.3 Beta build** and locate and enable that extension stubs there (it should be there): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/
2. Using the current PhpStorm version: Get the own copy of the latest stubs repository and specify the path at `Settings/Preferences | PHP | PHP Runtime | Advanced settings | Default stubs path`.

   Be careful with this one though: do not forget to clear it and switch back to the bundled version when you upgrade to 2023.3 version (outdated stubs can cause other issues -- providing wrong signature of the method/not recognizing newly added classes/methods etc). Or ensure to maintain the latest version of the stubs there yourself.
3. Using any PhpStorm version: Just get that single [opentelemetry.php](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/opentelemetry/opentelemetry.php) stub file and place it anywhere in your project so it gets indexed: the IDE will use it for code completion.

   The same: when you upgrade to 2023.3 or newer version then it's better to remove such a custom stub file and switch to the bundled stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562792/6521116) detailed explanation.

With help of [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone), I've tried below two ways, either is ok.

1. Config the stub path in PhpStorm,it should refer to the whole phpstorm stubs repo.[image]
2. Make a `.phpstorm.stubs` at the root directory of my project, and add the only [opentelemetry stub file](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/opentelemetry/opentelemetry.php) as refered in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562792/6521116).

[image]

Comment: *"I tried config the stub path in PhpStorm, but it not works, even when I reopen the PhpStorm or reload the interpreter."* Do you see the `opentelemetry` in the list of stubs? `Settings/Preferences | PHP | PHP Runtime` ?? You need to locate and enable that stub there (since it's not enabled by default). Another option is to try the "Sync Extensions with Interpreter" button there.

Comment: I cannot see the `opentelemetry` in the list of stubs, and there is no stubs list there too. I also tried "Sync Extensions with Interpreter", but neither works. I've add more info in my answer.

Comment: What did you put into that `stubs` folder exactly? As I understand it's just a single file... If so -- it;s wrong. I've just tried it all myself once again as per manual and it works just fine -- `opentelemetry` is listed under `Others` node -- https://i.imgur.com/evSAGoJ.png 1) Download ZIP of the **whole** stubs repo and unzip it (or git clone it locally) 2) Provide a path to that folder in PhpStorm settings 3) Accept the settings changes (Click "OK" to save the settings and close the Settings window). 4) Open the Settings again and check for the `opentelemetry` node.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstant your meanning, Ｉ just put the only opentelemetry.php file in the stubs folder.

After I download the whole phpstrom stubs repo, and refer to it. It works.

Thankyou again.